# Circular buffer with void pointer parameter

Tags: c

What is the right way to write this code?
I want to make a circular buffer that will receive as a parameter a pointer to some type of data. This way I wrote not working. I have problem with circular_buf_put function. It says invalid use of void expression. `error: invalid use of void expression cb->data[cb->head]=data;`
What is right way to use it here?

```
typedef struct circular_buf{
    void *data;
    size_t tail;
    size_t head;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t objectSize; 
    size_t size; 
} circular_buf;

int circular_buf_init(struct circular_buf *cb, void *data, size_t objectSize, size_t capacity)
  {
  cb->data=data;
  cb->objectSize=objectSize;
  cb->capacity=capacity;
  cb->tail=0;
  cb->head=0;
  cb->size=0;
   }

void circular_buf_put(circular_buf *cbuf, void  *data)
{
    cbuf->data[cbuf->head] = data;
    cbuf->head++;
    cbuf->size++;

}
```

Comment: IMHO, the *right way* to implement a circular buffer is with an array.  When using array, you can access elements by index.  This allows you to use the `%` operator to *wrap-around*.

Comment: You aren't updating the head at all, so you'll always overwrite the same slot.

Comment: You haven't provided a definition for `cbuf_handle_t` (or whatever `circular_buf_t` that I would assume it's a pointer to). Please provide enough information to be able to see the problem, and some details about what is specificially giving you that error.

Comment: For a start, read the descriptions of the tags you applied and then delete the wrong one! As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I updated my code. I am not sure is this the right way to write this line cbuf->data[cbuf->head] = data;
it says invalid use of void expression and I don't know what would be right way

Comment: are you using c or c++? please don't tag both

Comment: we still need a [mre]

Comment: @gag Describe the role of member `.objectSize`.

Comment: Are you going to store copies of data in your circular buffer (which `objectSize` implies), or are you going to store pointers-to-data (which using a `void *` implies)?

Answer (score 1):

> it say invalid use of void expression.

Because of this line:

```c
cbuf->data[cbuf->head] = data;
```

You are dereferencing a void pointer, which is illegal in C. You need to cast it to another type before you can dereference it.

Comment: Is there way to use it here but to dereferene in main?

Comment: @gag What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I want to make a universal buffer that will receive any type of data, and in the main I will determine which type it will be. My idea was to use a void pointer as the type of data that buffer will recieve but I'm not sure how to do it here.

Comment: @gag You can use `unsigned char *data` instead of `void *data` to be able to dereference it. See **0___________**'s answer.

Comment: @gag C has no _universal_ type for _any pointer_.  `void *` can enclode any _object pointer_, but may be too small for function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it this way. You do not need so much information in the structure. You only need to know the tail, head, size in elements and the element size.

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t tail;
    size_t head;
    size_t size; 
    size_t obj_size;
    unsigned char data[];
} circular_buf;

circular_buf *create(size_t size, size_t obj_size)
{
    circular_buf *cb = malloc(sizeof(*cb) + size * obj_size);
    if(cb)
    {
        cb -> tail = 0;
        cb -> head = 0;
        cb -> size = size;
        cb -> obj_size = obj_size;
    }
    return cb;
}

size_t inc(size_t val, circular_buf *cb)
{
    if(val == cb -> size - 1) val = 0;
    else val++;

    return val;
}

int circular_buf_put(circular_buf *cb, const void *data)
{
    size_t new_tail = inc(cb -> tail, cb);
    if (new_tail == cb -> head) return -1; // buffer full
    memcpy(&cb->data[cb -> tail * cb -> size], data, cb -> obj_size);
    cb -> tail = new_tail;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice use of `malloc(sizeof(*cb) + size * obj_size)`.